# converting noteCount to binary for tumblr theme

Tags: javascript

I want to convert post note counter to binary. I have a javascript code, but I don't know how to make it work with the counter. Need your help.

```
{block:NoteCount}
  <div class="notes">
    {NoteCount}
  </div>
{/block:NoteCount}
```

and

```
function tobinary(n) {
     ....................
     ....................
     ....................
     document.write(r);
}
```

The function could do anything (like converting number to words; binary is just an example).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: I just need to know how to make a function work with {NoteCount}. Any function, not specific one

Answer (score 0):

To pass NoteCount value to JavaScript function put below code in your file:

```
<script>
   tobinary({NoteCount});
</script>
```